# Typescript - Problems with the lexical scoping => this

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript, this

My Problem is with the following function:

```
() => this.handleRes(res, this.lobbyInitFn(this.$log, this.lobbyData))
```

What is the best way to get a reference to my `lobbyData` variable on the Ctrl? 
As a result of the fat arrow syntax I get a pointer to the global `window` object.

At the moment I just get a reference to `$log` function in the `lobbyInitFn` method and an undefined for the `dataCol` parameter.

```
module lobby.controllers {
  'use strict';

  class LobbyCtrl{
    public lobbyData : Array<string>;

    constructor(private $scope, private $log : ng.ILogService, private lobbyStorage) {
      this.init();
    }

     private init(){
      this.initializeLobbyData();
    }

    private initializeLobbyData(){
      var res = this.lobbyStorage.LobbyRoom().query(
        () => this.handleRes(res, this.lobbyInitFn(this.$log, this.lobbyData)),
        () => this.handleErr("Error while initializing the lobby data."));
    }

     private lobbyInitFn(logger, dataCol){
      return function(data){
        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; ++i) {
          logger.log(data[i]);
        }
        dataCol = data;
      }
    }

    // Common functions => outsourcing
    private handleRes(res : any, resFn? : callbackFn) {
      if(typeof resFn != 'undefined') {
        resFn(res)
      } else{
        this.$log.log(res);
      }
    }

    private handleErr(err : string, errFn? : callbackFn) {
      if(typeof errFn != 'undefined') {
        errFn(err)
      } else{
        this.$log.error(err);
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: Where is `lobbyData` coming from? It's never declared in the constructor function, the `init` function nor the `initializeLobbyData` function.

Comment: Good point - I've rewritten the whole example and forgot the initialisation in the constructor => `this.lobbyData = [];`. Now I do get a reference but the data gets lost. How do I need to rewrite it with closure that I can access the property?

Comment: Since you are declaring an empty array what data is there to lose? Do you have some data object somewhere else that you are expecting should magically populate `lobbyData`?

Comment: after I populate the array with data, it eventually gets lost when it leaves the callback function.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try:

```
() => this.handleRes(res, () => this.lobbyInitFn(this.$log, this.lobbyData))
```

Comment: this way the return function doesn't get executed, thanks for helping though.

Comment: Any chance you could create a plunkr?

Comment: for some reason I get a reference to the $log function from angular but not to my class property. I guess that has something to do with the implementation of the logger.